# Delete all or none in SQL Join

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join

My tables:

```
SalesOrderHead
    id
     1
     2
     3


SalesOrder
    id  SalesOrderHeadID
     1                 1
     2                 1
     3                 1

JobOrder
    id  SalesOrderID
     1             1
     2             2
     3             3
```

I want to delete from `SalesOrderHead` and `SalesOrder`, if none of the rows that belong to a given `SalesOrderHead` in `SalesOrder` exist in `JobOrder`. i.e. if any of the `SalesOrder` rows exist in `JobOrder` it should rollback.
Right now if I write a wrong query like this.

```
DELETE
    SO
FROM
    SalesOrder SO
    LEFT JOIN JobOrder JO ON
        JO.SalesOrderLineID = SO.id
WHERE
    JO.id IS NULL
    AND
    SO.id in
    (
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            SalesOrder
        WHERE
            SalesOrderID = 1
    )

Delete from SalesOrderHead where id = 1
```

It will delete some rows from `SalesOrder`.

Comment: If you're seeing related data being deleted, it's likely you have `ON DELETE CASCADE` set-up in your database, or a `TRIGGER`. What is the full table and relationship (foreign key constraint) definitions?

Comment: ```SalesOrder
FK_SalesOrder_SalesOrderHead
JobOrder
FK_JobOrder_SalesOrder```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IN` and `NOT IN`.

```
Delete from SalesOrderHead where id in (
    select id from SalesOrder where id not in (
        select SalesOrderLineID from JobOrder
    )
)
```

Comment: I want to delete from both SalesOrderHead and SalesOrder.
SalesOrderHeadID is fk in SalesOrder.
SalesOrderLineID is fk in JobOrder

Comment: @awaisharoon, mysql?

Comment: microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query as:

```
--Store deleted Id's from Primary table: SalesOrderHead
DECLARE @tblDeletedID TABLE ( ID INT );

DELETE FROM  SOH 
OUTPUT DELETED.id INTO @tblDeletedID 
FROM SalesOrderHead AS SOH
where  SOH.id not in 
 (select SO.SalesOrderHeadID
  from SalesOrder SO 
  join JobOrder JO on JO.SalesOrderID = SO.id
 )

--Now delete from child table: SalesOrder
DELETE from SO
FROM SalesOrder SO 
INNER JOIN @tblDeletedID Deleted  
ON SO.SalesOrderHeadID = Deleted.id;
```

[Sample code here..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a33e9f0c96e00c409a507ec6f4f309ed)

Comment: deleting from SO head first throws `FK_SalesOrder_SalesOrderHead` reference constraint conflict. The delete has to be first from `JobOrder`, then the `SalesOrder` and finally `SalesOrerHead` because of the foreign key constraints.

Comment: in my c# code. I do this delete from joborder, then the salesorder,
then in same transaction I delete from salesOrderHead, that generates foreignkey exception if there exist record in the database tables "salesOrder". So then I rollback this transaction. This solves my problem, but is this correct approach?

Comment: not delete from JobOrder. I check if `SalesOrder`exists in JobOrder if not, delete it.